# Google Drive API uploads all files to one account

Tags: php, google-drive-api

There is a problem with uploading files by GoogleDrive API PHP. I have two accounts A and B, a authorize as A user upload files, all is ok, than I authorize as B user and try to upload file and it uploads to A user's drive! I checked access tokens they are differs, I authorized as B user. Session is clear, tried from another computer from C account, result the same, it uploads to A account drive, few hours later I can authorize as D user and all next uploads from another accounts will be to his google drive.

I authorize as

```
public static function auth($state, $config) {
    $client = self::getGoogleClient($config);
    $client->setState($state);
    $auth_url = $client->createAuthUrl();
    return filter_var($auth_url, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL);
}
```

$config is array of needle data as client_id, client_secret, redirect_url etc.

```
public static function uploadFile($access_token, $uploadFile, $fileName, $config) {
    if (!isset($access_token)) {
        return;
    }

    $userId = \HttpReceiver\HttpReceiver::get('userId', 'string');
    $client = self::getGoogleClient($config);
    try {
        $access_token = (array)$access_token;
        $client->setAccessToken($access_token);
    }catch (\InvalidArgumentException $e){
        return array('status' => 'error', 'msg' => 'refreshToken', 'url' => self::auth($userId, $config));
    }

    $service = new \Google_Service_Drive($client);

    //Insert a file
    $file = new \Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile();
    new \Google_Service_Drive_User();

    if (!isset($fileName) || strlen($fileName) == 0 || $fileName == '0') {
        $tmp = explode('/', $uploadFile);
        $fileName = $tmp[sizeof($tmp) - 1];
    }else{
        $fileName .= '.'.self::getExtension($uploadFile);
    }

    $file->setTitle($fileName);
    $file->setDescription('A test document');
    $file->setMimeType(self::getMime(self::getExtension($uploadFile)));
    $data = file_get_contents($uploadFile);
    $folderInfo = self::getFolder($access_token, $config);
    $id = 0;
    if($folderInfo['status'] === 'ok'){
        $id = $folderInfo['id'];
    }else{
        return array('status' => 'error', 'msg' => 'refreshToken', 'url' => self::auth($userId, $config));
    }
    $parent = new \Google_Service_Drive_ParentReference();
    $parent->setId($id);
    $file->setParents(array($parent));
    try {
        $createdFile = $service->files->insert($file, array(
            'data' => $data,
            'mimeType' => self::getMime(self::getExtension($uploadFile)),
            'uploadType' => 'media'
        ));

    }catch(\Exception $e){
        return array('status' => 'error', 'msg' => 'refreshToken', 'url' => self::auth($userId, $config));
    }

    if(isset($createdFile) && isset($createdFile['id']) && strlen($createdFile['id']) > 0){
        return array('status' => 'ok');
    }else{
        return array('status' => 'error', 'msg' => 'refreshToken', 'url' => self::auth($userId, $config));
    }
}
```

$createdFile has info about owner and it shosw that owner is A user, but I use access_token of B user

Get google client func

```
private static function getGoogleClient($config) {
    $client = new \Google_Client();

    $config = self::getGoogleConfig($config);

    $client->setAuthConfig($config);

    //$client->setAuthConfigFile($config);

    $userId = \HttpReceiver\HttpReceiver::get('userId', 'int');

    if(!isset($userId)){
        $userId = \HttpReceiver\HttpReceiver::get('state', 'int');
    }

    $client->setRedirectUri($config['GOOGLEDRIVE_REDIRECT2']);
    $client->addScope(\Google_Service_Drive::DRIVE);
    return $client;
}
```

Comment: when I done print_r($service->about->get());
It shows A account

Comment: SOLVED
Answer is easy enough. Just set $client->setCache(new \Google_Cache_Null());